# How many numbers between $1000$ and $100000$ that do not contain digits $2, 7, 8$.

Tags: combinatorics

I would like to know how to calculate the amount of numbers between 1000 and 100000 that do not contain 2,7 or 8. I had this question in my exam today and, since I have never been able to do probability and combinatorics properly, it's very likely I got it wrong. Could you please show me how to calculate it?

What I thought was: for 4 digit integers, calculate the total amount of possible numbers. Then calculate all numbers which do not contain 2,7 or 8 and deduce that from the total amount of 4 digit numbers. Repeat process for 5 digit integers and sum them up.

Any sense to this?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Hint: writing decimal numbers between $1000_{10}$ and $100000_{10}$ which do not contain the $3$ given digits is equivalent to writing the numbers in base $10-3=7$ between $1000_7$ and $100000_7$.

Comment: Very interesting approach! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

*I only have an elementary understanding of combinatorics*

Think of all the numbers between 1000 and 100,000 as five digit numbers (i.e 1000 is actually 01000). How many numbers five digit numbers are there, well the short answer is 100,000 and we can arrive at this by saying that we have 10 choices for the first digit, and 10 for the second, etc to find that we have $10^5=100,000$ numbers. But hang on, some of these are numbers like 000100 which isn't in our range, what restrictions do we have? Well at least one of the first two numbers has to be non zero, so we only have 99 choices for the first two ($10^2=100$, $-1$ for the option 00) So we have 99 choices for the first two digits, and then $10^3$ choices for the next three giving us $99*10*10*10=99,000$. Hurray, we have what we expected, 100,000-1000 is is 99,000.

Whilst that isn't ground breaking, we can add some details in. Instead of 10 choices for each digit, we don't want a 2,7,8 (anywhere) so we actually only have 7 choices for each digit. Also, we still need one of the first two digits to be non zero, so we have $7*7 -1$ choices for the first digit, and then $7^3$ for the remaining 3 digits, this gives $48*343=16464$ numbers. There are some edge cases here, this includes the number 1000 but not 100,000.

On a smaller scale, how many numbers between 10 and 100 are there without a 2,7 or 8. Again we need the first digit to be non zero so we have 6 choices, and the second digit we have 7 choices. Giving us 42. They are:

10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 19 =7

30, 31, 33, 34, 35, 36, 39, = 7

40, 41, 43, 44, 45, 46, 49, = 7

50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 59 = 7

60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 69 = 7

90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 99 = 7

Total is 42. 43 if you include 100, 41 if you don't include 10 (there is ambiguity with the word between).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

HINT....Assuming that repetition is allowed and you can't start with a zero, you have a choice of 6 digits for the first place and 7 for each of the following places, so...considering the four and five digit numbers separately, you have....can you finish this?

Answer (score 0):

- Label digits from left to right A,B,C,D,E,F.
- First, count only $5$-digit numbers (B to F), then add $1$ to the count for $100000$.
- For each digit there are $7$ numbers to choose from.
- BC cannot be $00$ for a $5$-digit number.

Number of integers from $1000$ to $100000$ (inclusive) without any digit being $2,7,8$ is given by:
$$\overbrace{1}^{100000}+(\underbrace{7}_B\times \underbrace{7}_C-\underbrace{1}_{BC=00})\cdot (\underbrace{7}_D\times \underbrace{7}_E\times \underbrace{7}_F)=16465$$